# Парсер информации пользователя Instagram PHP

Tags: php, парсер, curl, instagram

Итак, начнем.
**Задача** - получить значение количества подписчиков пользователя Instagram по никнейму (@name) средствами PHP.
Что уже пробовал:

1. *Парсинг страницы курлом или file_get_contents().*
   Как правило Ip хостингов и большинства прокси раздач находятся в бане Instagram. Из-за этого ответ от запроса не приходит.
2. *API Graphh и API Display. Очень замудренная вещь оказалась, как и в принципе все продукты facebook,но разобравшись понял, что тоже не подходит. Для логирования необходимы ключи доступа и тп.*

Хочется получить полезный опыт от людей, который реализовали уже эту простую на первый взгляд задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял зачем тут прокси. Реализовывал пару-тройку месяцев назад курлом, в который только user-agent заголовок добавил и всё, только запрашивал JSON инфу, а не саму страницу профиля.

Добавьте к адресу страницы ?__a=1.

Примерно так https://www.instagram.com/souloftrue/?__a=1.

На выходе будет JSON с полной инфой по профилю.
[image: insta]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
Знаю об этом способе, но через хостинг тоже не получается отобразить ответ. Можете прислать пример с user agent. Я пробовал с таким
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

Comment: @Lelik ну так ошибку себе надо выводить, может дело не в бане айпи хостинга. юзерагент я бы смотрел в последнюю очередь.